# openGraph API - How do i store profile image in mysql

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a legacy registration system , whic takes a file input as a field for the user to upload their profile picture. I am now using opengraph to supplement this system. I am able to connect successfully, but am stuck at how to connect the  to the link of the picture that i get from facebook.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

http://graph.facebook.com/the-username/picture alway redirects to the picture in thumbnail 
here for a larger version:
http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture?type=large
you can also do an fql query in the user table for several fields which are listed here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user